# (Done) Please vote to reopen "How should I deal with an employee who is stealing from the cash counter"

Tags: discussion

Please vote to reopen [How should I deal with an employee who is stealing from the cash counter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122628/how-should-i-deal-with-an-employee-who-is-stealing-from-the-cash-counter)

It is not off-topic and should not have been closed, IMHO. It already has several good answers.

And sadly, it's not an unusual occurrence in the retail workspace.

Comment: I am amazed (or perhaps not) that such clearly answerable question was closed! Casted the second vote.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - I am saddened, but no longer amazed.

Comment: 3rd cast, 2 to go

Answer (score 3):

The post is open again now. Which was *clearly* answerable and valuable since the beginning.

Comment: luckily, it is protected now.

Comment: Sadly, that won't prevent future closings :/